# Exception on empty linq query result

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to add filters to my MVC application. I am somewhat successful in this because i can return a filtered value if its present in the db.

However when its not present in the db i want it to return an empty list. Since Linq should be returning empty if the results are zero. however i have used try catch to catch any exceptions if for some reason an code statements fail, and if the fields entered do not match any db entry, the linq query breaks into catch and the exception is null.

I have no idea what is wrong it shouldn't even be breaking into catch.

**Linq Query:**

```
 if (attr1 == "null" && attr3 != "null" && attr2 != "null")
    {
       attr1 = "%";

         Size = db.GetFilterResultCount(index, Size, attr1, attr2, attr3).Count();
         accountlist = db.GetFilterResult(index, Size, attr1, attr2, attr3).ToList();

         filteredlist.GetList = accountlist;
         filteredlist.index = index;
         filteredlist.size = Size;
         filteredlist.totalSize = db.Accounts.Count();
         filteredlist.resultSize = db.GetFilterResultCount(index, Size, attr1, attr2, attr3).Count();
    }
```

This is one of the many conditions i am using to check which field is being filtered. But the linq query is the same for everyone of those.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFilterResult]
@PageIndex INT,  
@pageSize INT,
@attr1 nvarchar(300),
@attr2 nvarchar(300),
@attr3 nvarchar(300)

    AS
    Begin
    SELECT  Accounts.firstName, Accounts.lastName, Accounts.Email, 
     Accounts.dateOfBirth, Accounts.phoneNo, Countries.CountryName 

    FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Countries On Accounts.CountryID = 
     Countries.CountryID

    Where (Accounts.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr1, '%') and 
     Accounts.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr2, '%') and Accounts.CountryID 
      Like CONCAT('%', @attr3, '%')) 

    ORDER BY UserId OFFSET @PageSize*(@PageIndex-1) ROWS FETCH NEXT 
     @PageSize ROWS ONLY;

    END
```

**GetFilterResultCount:**

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFilterResult]
@PageIndex INT,  
@pageSize INT,
@attr1 nvarchar(300),
@attr2 nvarchar(300),
@attr3 nvarchar(300)

    AS
    Begin
    SELECT  Accounts.firstName, Accounts.lastName, Accounts.Email, 
     Accounts.dateOfBirth, Accounts.phoneNo, Countries.CountryName 

    FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Countries On Accounts.CountryID = 
     Countries.CountryID

    Where (Accounts.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr1, '%') and 
     Accounts.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', @attr2, '%') and Accounts.CountryID 
      Like CONCAT('%', @attr3, '%')) 


    END
```

Comment: Wait, how can the outer exception have an inner exception if the outer exception is null?

Comment: it doesn't have it. The outer exception is null. hence i i have no idea what the problem is. I ll fix that in the question

Comment: How did you check that `outer exception is null`? did u try to add breakpoint in your  `Exception ex` in `catch` block?

Comment: Yes! And i found the problem. I just commented the try catch and Visual Studio gave me another exception which stated that i cannot return a result with zero rows it has to be greater than zero. but i now i am confused why the try catch didnt catch this exception.

Comment: could u plz add your full code bcoz posted code does not sufficient to resolve your problem

Comment: May we have GetFilterResultCount source?

Comment: @reshoaib The code is pretty big and i don't see how anything else is relevant to the problem. If you could specify what you are looking for then i might be able to post it.

Comment: @MiladAghamohammadi i will add it but its the same as the sql procedure except for one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The try catch wasn't working fine i removed it and i instantly got an exception which stated: "Cannot return result less than 1" or something similar. SO basically the result needed atleast more than 1 rows probably because of this Line.

```
    ORDER BY UserId OFFSET @PageSize*(@PageIndex-1) ROWS FETCH NEXT 
 @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

hence i added a condition that checked the result size first and if it was zero instead of return using the stored procedure above i simply returned an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

This is not your answer but you are trying ignore attr1 where clause, when attr1 == "null". You can use IFNULL function in your query

```
Where (Accounts.firstName LIKE  CONCAT('%', IFNULL(@attr1, Accounts.firstName), '%') and
```

and pass null to stored procedure

```
   attr1 = null;
   accountlist = db.GetFilterResult(index, Size, attr1, attr2, attr3).ToList();
```

Comment: This could be useful but still doesn't really solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure is a simple SQL select. This means that the stored procedure will return an empty list if no items match your SQL WHERE.

You forgot to tell use the type of your `db`, and especially `db.GetFilterResult`. Did you make this yourself, or is your `db` class smart that it automatically knows which stored procedure to call.

If you created it yourself, it will look similar to:

```
IEnumerable<Account> GetFilterResultCount(...)
{
     try
     {
          var fetchedData = CallStoredProcedure();
          foreach(var fetchedRow in fetchedData)
          {
              // use fetched data to create a new account object
              Account account = new Account() {... use fetchedData }
              yield return account;
          }
     }
     catch (Exception exc)
     {
         // TODO: decide what to do with this exception. Log and continue?
         // return empty sequence as if no Accounts where available
     }
}
```

This will return an empty sequence if stored procedure returned empty selection or if exception. If the call to your stored procedure returns `null` if nothing selected (very unusual) you should check on null return:

```
 var fetchedData = CallStoredProcedure();
 if (fetchedData != null)
 {
     foreach(var fetchedRow in fetchedData) ...
```

Some people don't like to use `yield` and prefer LINQ-only (although LINQ internally yields).

```
try
{
    var fetchedData = CallStoredProcedure();
    if (fetchedData == null)
    {   // nothing fetched, return empty sequence
        return Enumerable.Empty<Account>();
    }
    else
    {
         return fetchedData.Select(fetchedRow => new Account() {...};
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{   // problem fetching data, return empty sequence
    return Enumerable.Empty<Account>();
}
```

If you are familiar with `yield return`, then I'm not sure whether the LINQ solution is more readable / maintainable.

Usage:

```
var accountlist = db.GetFilterResult(index, Size, attr1, attr2, attr3)
    .ToList();
```

If you can't change `db.GetFilterResult`, I guess it's best to write your own

```
IEnumerable<Account> FetchFilterResultData(...)
{
     var fetchedData = db.GetFilterResult(...);
     // return emtpy sequence if null returned:
     return fetchedData ?? Enummerable.Empty<Account>();

     // TODO: exception handling needed?
}
```

Usage:

```
var accountlist = this.FetchFilterResultData(index, Size, attr1, attr2, attr3)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes i made it myself, I am using entity framework and using the db first approach. which means after i declare the db and make the entity all the procedure and table classes are automatically generated and later i am calling them using db.class, In this case db.GetFilterResult.